# How can I tell smbclient not to translate a particular forward slash into a backward slash?

Tags: command, escaping, smb, slash

The smbclient utility seems to unconditionally translate forward slashes in the command being passed to the remote Windows system. That might make sense when they are part of a path in the remote file system - smbclient thinks it's helping the user avoid mistakes. But not in a case like this:

```
auth='-Ubldguru%secret11'
homedir='\AutoHelp\prod'
UNC='//build2.company.com/c$'

keith@build1:~/build2> smbclient $auth --directory $homedir $UNC --command 'dir'
Domain=[BUILDDOM] OS=[Windows 7 Professional 7601 Service Pack 1] Server=[Windows 7 Professional 6.1]
  .                                   D        0  Mon Jun 15 13:19:31 2015
  ..                                  D        0  Mon Jun 15 13:19:31 2015
  adldap                              D        0  Wed Jun 10 15:37:14 2015
  jdfoutput                           D        0  Wed Jun 10 15:39:49 2015
  Version34                           D        0  Wed Jun 10 15:34:39 2015
  WORKING                             A        8  Mon Jun 15 10:33:02 2015
  _COMMON_DITA                        D        0  Tue Jun  9 15:11:21 2015
  _COMMON_GRAPHICS                    D        0  Tue Jun  9 15:11:36 2015

                51174 blocks of size 4194304. 38373 blocks available
keith@build1:~/build2> smbclient $auth --directory $homedir $UNC --command 'dir /s'
Domain=[BUILDDOM] OS=[Windows 7 Professional 7601 Service Pack 1] Server=[Windows 7 Professional 6.1]
NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_FILE listing \s
keith@build1:~/build2> smbclient $auth --directory $homedir $UNC --command 'dir \/s'
Domain=[BUILDDOM] OS=[Windows 7 Professional 7601 Service Pack 1] Server=[Windows 7 Professional 6.1]
NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_FILE listing \\s
keith@build1:~/build2> smbclient $auth --directory $homedir $UNC --command 'dir \\/s'
Domain=[BUILDDOM] OS=[Windows 7 Professional 7601 Service Pack 1] Server=[Windows 7 Professional 6.1]
NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_FILE listing \\\s
keith@build1:~/build2> smbclient $auth --directory $homedir $UNC --command 'dir \\\/s'
Domain=[BUILDDOM] OS=[Windows 7 Professional 7601 Service Pack 1] Server=[Windows 7 Professional 6.1]
NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_FILE listing \\\\s
keith@build1:~/build2> smbclient $auth --directory $homedir $UNC --command 'dir \\\\/s'
Domain=[BUILDDOM] OS=[Windows 7 Professional 7601 Service Pack 1] Server=[Windows 7 Professional 6.1]
NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_FILE listing \\\\\s
keith@build1:~/build2>
```

As you can see in the above, smbclient (and I) know how to get a simple listing at the remote end. The problem is passing flags, which are given with a forward slash, to the remote command. ALL slashes seen by smbclient as it parses its ARGVs are blindly converted to backslashes, and I have found no way to escape the ones that should be forward/plain/real slashes.

(It might have been easier to find help "out there" - provided it even exists - if the man page for smbclient didn't speak specifically of the slashes around the UNC string.)

Am I missing something in the man page? Should I read the source code? Is this well known?

Keith

Answer (score 0):

You don't. The `smbclient` `dir` command does not take the same options as the `dir` command in Windows. The one and only parameter it recognizes is an optional "mask" / wildcard pattern. It has no use for forward slashes.

See the full documentation at https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smbclient.1.html

Comment: I get it now. :/ The "dir command" is not the system "dir" command in the same way as if I had typed it into cmd.exe. That's sad (for me), but I guess I can filter locally.